# Confusion about a probability question.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$90$ students, including Joe and Jane, are to be split into three classes of equal size, and this is to be done at random. What is the probability that Joe and Jane end up in the same class?

The answer given is $\frac{29}{89}$. One explanation is "put Joe in one class, then, Jane has a $\frac{29}{89}$ chance of choosing to be in the same class". I also found the combinatorics answer $$\frac{3\binom{88}{28}}{\binom{90}{30}}.$$I don't understand why it wouldn't just be $\frac 13$. $9$ ways to split Jane and Joe up, and in $3$ of those $9$ ways, they are together. I don't see why the other $88$ students matter.

Comment: Because having assigned Joe it is now slightly less likely that Jane will be put in the same class (as that class has $29$ empty seats and the other two have $30$ each).  Try it with $6$ students.  Now the correct answer is $\frac 15$....significantly different from $\frac 13$.

Comment: @lulu If we have $\ 3\ $ students, the probability is even $\ 0\ $ :)

Comment: @Peter True! $\quad $

Comment: If we have $\ 3n\ $ students, the probability is $$\ \frac{n-1}{3n-1}\ $$ which tends to $\ \frac{1}{3}\ $ , if $\ n\ $ tends to $\ \infty\ $